# ColdFusion: Object not creating of .Net dll file

Tags: .net, object, dll, coldfusion

I am going to create object of .net dll file to access its function but it generate an error. I also re-install ColdFusion 10 .NET Integration Service Installer, but it not resolve. 
Here is my code.

`<cftry>
    <cfscript>
        variables.dotNetObject = createObject("dotnet", "Calculator.Calculator", "D:/Calculator.dll").init();
        WriteDump(variables.dotNetObject);
    </cfscript>
    <cfcatch>
        <cfdump var="#cfcatch#">
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>`

And here is the Calculator.dll file.

`using System;
namespace Calculator
{
    public class Calculator
    {
        public int addition(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}`

Here is the error message which i got

`Message: Calculator.Calculator
ID: CF_CFPAGE
Line: 3
Type: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the complete error message? Can you load *any* .net objects successfully? Try [the example at the bottom of the documentation](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfobject%3A+.NET+object). It uses core classes, rather than a custom dll file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is related to object type that you are specifying.
The object type in case of .Net objects should be `".NET"`
Please read this http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-789e.html

```
<cfobject type = ".NET" name = "dotNetObject" class = "Calculator" 
        assembly = "D:/Calculator.dll"> 
<cfset sum = dotNetObject.addition(1,2)>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply @Pankaj. I change the 'dotnet' to '.net' but it not effect the error. :(

Comment: *The object type ...should be `.NET`* No. If you check the docs, either ".NET" or "dotnet" are acceptable.